# Rollback of parent hibernate transaction , which has multiple committed child transactions

Tags: sql, database, hibernate, transactions, hibernate-criteria

I have one parent hibernate transaction which creates let's say 5 child transactions and if any one of the child transaction rollbacks , parent transaction should also rollback.
Now, if 4 child transactions have committed but 5th child transaction rollbacks, as per my logic parent transaction should also rollback.
Now, what happens to 4 committed child transactions? 
Will they also rollback, if parent rollbacks?

Comment: It's been a while from this post, but for new readers I think that it's depends on which propagation mode did you use, if you are using the PROPAGATION_REQUIRED strategy it will create a logical transaction for each single methods (piece of code) and if one of those methods fails it will rollback the 5 methods